# EC2 Instance with 'This site can’t be reached' error

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am always getting *'This site can’t be reached'* error when trying to access the ip address of my EC2 instance.

This is happening for all ip addresses (Public IPv4 address, Public IPv4 DNS, Private IPv4 addresses, Private IPv4 DNS) and for all EC2 instances I create. Particularly, I am trying to run WordPress from my EC2 following [this guide](https://medium.com/@babette.landmesser/install-wordpress-in-aws-ec2-instance-ada5b2db06d2). All the installation runs fine but still the ip is unavailable.

Here are some proposed solutions I tried but didn't solve the issue:

- My inbound and outbound security rules are already allowing ssh (port 22), http (port 80) and https (port 443) from all origins (0.0.0.0/0, ::/0).
- I disactivated my Windows firewall. Anyway, I can't access from other computers or from my mobile either.
- The ec2 created is the basic Linux 2 t2.micro (exactly as in the guide) and I have tried reaching the ip from a brand new ec2 instance without WordPress or anything and the same happens. Am I expected to get anything from the ip of a brand new ec2 at all?
- I can connect with ssh without issues.

I am a root user under the free tier, is there any impact?

Would really appreciate if someone could tell where else to look as most solutions on internet point to the list above and none of them solved my case.

Comment: The fact that you can connect to the instance via SSH means that the networking side is working, and you say that port 80 is open. This then suggests that the instance is _not_ serving any content on port 80. You should SSH into the instance, then run `curl localhost` -- this will attempt to access the web server on the local computer without going across the network. It should return the HTML of the website. Let us know what happens.

Comment: "Am I expected to get anything from the ip of a brand new ec2 at all?"  On port 80 or 443?  No.  You need to install a webserver and start it up.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks a lot for the quick answer. That is correct, I am getting the Apache Server html Hello World in the console when running `curl localhost`. Still, the ip is unreachable from the browser.

Comment: Okay. The next step is to SSH into the instance, then run `curl http://<private-ip-address>`, which will connect to the local web server via the private IP address. Let us know if it works. Then, run `curl http://<public-ip-address>` and let us know if it works. By the way, it seems odd that the Apache Server is returning Hello World rather than returning the WordPress home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried that guide for myself.

There are a few typos around `wp --info` (it should be two dashes, no space).

Also, in the **WordPress Installation**, it says:

> Navigate to /var/www/html and run:

```
$ wp core download.
```

It isn't too clear that **you should first type** `cd /var/www/html` so that WordPress installs in that directory.

Also, there should *not* be a period at the end of: `wp core download`

With those fixes, it installed WordPress and I was able to connect to the configuration page where it was asking for database details.

Comment: Minding the fixes you spotted solved it and I can now reach the public ip, thanks